# How to use SocketIO in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, socket.io

I have found this [link](https://github.com/fpanettieri/unity-socket.io) to use socket.io in unity, but I am unable to configure it.

This is my Unity code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

void Start () {
        GameObject go = GameObject.Find("SocketIO");//GameObject returns Null
        SocketIOComponent socket = go.GetComponent<SocketIOComponent>();

    }  

    void Update () {

    }
}
```

The guide says that i have to **"Configure the url where your Socket.IO server is listening"** but i am unable to do that.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others with this issue.

I hadn't added the SocketIO prefab in the game(Drag-Drop in Game Hierarchy) that's why I was getting the error. Just add the prefab in the **Game Hierarchy** and change server address from inspector.